# How use Sub function wth GetAtt in serverless?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

Consider the following code:

```
EventRule:
  Type: AWS::Events::Rule
  Properties:
    Description: "ny trigger"
    ScheduleExpression: "rate(1 minute)"
    State: "DISABLED"
    Targets:
      -
        Arn: !GetAtt MyFunctionLambdaFunction.Arn
        Id: "someId"
        Input:
          Fn::Sub:
            - '{"arn":"#{arn}"}'
            - arn: !GetAtt MyStateMachine.Arn
```

This gives me en error:

```
Error: The CloudFormation template is invalid: Template error: One or more Fn::Sub 
intrinsic functions don't specify expected arguments. Specify a string as first argument,
and an optional second argument to specify a mapping of values to replace in the string
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `GetAtt` in `Sub` here. `Sub` can resolve things like `MyStateMachine.Arn`. So you can just do something like:

```
Input: !Sub 
  - |-
    { "arn": "${MyStateMachine.Arn}" }
```

In some cases you might still need to pass in parameters (for instance when you need to call functions like `ImportValue`). For instance, if your state machine is defined in a different stack and is exported via `other-stack-MyStateMachine-Arn` output, you can do the following:

```
Input: !Sub 
  - |-
    { "arn": "${MyStateMachineArn}" }
  - MyStateMachineArn: !ImportValue 
      'Fn::Sub': 'other-stack-MyStateMachine-Arn'
```

Comment: First example can be shortened to:
`Input: !Sub | <newline>
    { "arn": "${MyStateMachine.Arn}" }`
or
`Input: !Sub '{ "arn": "${MyStateMachine.Arn}" }'`